# Are firebase generated keys ordered?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a an array of ids which are generated using the firebase.ref().push() method. 
For example -

```
myarray = 
[-KoDeiUiqsMKDuXuwhzi, 
-KoDrz6ngJtNrr51tguD,
-KoDyC-_ZeSIAN1_oFk4]
```

I have a node of items some of which match these ids -

```
/mynode
  --KoDeiUiqsMKDuXuwhzi 
     -itemprop1 : "abc"
     -itemprop2 : "xyz"
     -id : "KoDeiUiqsMKDuXuwhzi"
  --KnurYH554YNW6bcWch5
     -itemprop1 : "opq"
     -itemprop2 : "zyc"
     -id : "KnurYH554YNW6bcWch5"
  --KoDrz6ngJtNrr51tguD
     -itemprop1 : "mon"
     -itemprop2 : "ooo"
     -id : "KoDrz6ngJtNrr51tguD"
          ..
          ..
          ..
          ..
```

..and so on.. basically the array of id's is a subset of this node.
I want to retreive a all objects from this node where the id matches in the array.
Currently the way i am doing is like this -

```
firebase.database().ref("mynode").once('value').then(function(snap){
   snap.forEach(function(childsnap){
     if(myarray.indexOf(childsnap.key) != -1){
        //add to result
      }
   })
})
```

Although this code works but i think i can use orderByChild, startAt and endAt filtering to get the list of objects.
Is there a way to get the result by filtering instead of getting all data and then filtering out? Will it be more efficient than this code?

Comment: If you already know the ids you're looking for, you could also simply query them each directly at the their known paths rather than pulling down everything.

Comment: yes i realise that but wouldnt that mean i have to query for every item in a loop?

Comment: I don't think that would be the worst thing, especially if you would otherwise be pulling down a lot of data you don't need.

Comment: Looping reads are not as slow as you may think, since they are pipelined over the same socket connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786